# Trouble uploading to iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, upload, certificate, app-store-connect, provisioning

Im a beginner in app development and I'm having some trouble uploading to iTunes connect.

I have an update to an app that I want to upload for testing after I fixed some issues.

I have only added some background music to the app but it refuses to upload and hangs at uploading to iTunes Store. I have read the many posts on the subject and followed all of the answers and I still can't get it uploaded, I've been trying for days and days now.

I even tried to update with a version wth no changes just the version number bumped up .01 
I have completely remade all my certificates on the developer site and all the provisioning profiles have been updated. Tried restarting Xcode my router and re downloading my certificates, deleting all provisioning profiles and so on. Im still not getting anywhere. Is there anything else I can try ?

Also ive tried using different networks but to no avail.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. My next step is to delete Xcode from my computer and remove all traces and start from the beggining again

im tearing my hair out at the moment

Comment: Also can I add I installed cocoa pods for another app that I was working on could this cause a problem, If so how to remove all traces of it from my system

Comment: looks like a proxy issue ( sometimes error on iTunesConnect side ). Have your tried uploading your binary using application loader? Refer to this link for uploading instructions http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/e3#/apdATD1E12-D1E1A1303-D1E12A1126

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I should have added yes I have tried that too, the only thing I haven't tried is uploading using two instances of application loader. The problem has been going on since 28th April so I honestly think it's something I'm doing wrong myself not something on apples side

Comment: You don't need 2 instances of application loader I think issue with your proxy settings/firewall settings. Try this link final time - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803 and if issue still persists try opening up a technical ticket with apple - https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/. You get 2 tickets with your itunes account

Comment: Im trying it now ill let you know the results, the command seems to take a long time to work though, or I can't see any result after a minute anyway

Comment: Hi, that didn't work either I'm going to open a support ticket with apple

Comment: update this thread once you find a solution, so that others can be benefited